# Node 16 build fails in Dockerfile - class SocksProxyAgent extends agent_base_1.Agent

Tags: node.js, docker

The Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.17.1-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    python3 \
    py3-pip \
    git \
    openssh-client \
    vim \
    jq \
    aws-cli \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add --no-cache yarn

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN HOME=/kaniko/ yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["sh", "startup.sh"]
```

When I run docker build I get the following error:

```
$ npm run build:types && npm run build:js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/index.js:110
class SocksProxyAgent extends agent_base_1.Agent {
                                           ^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/index.js:110:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js:174:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
```

The error started after I updated the Node to 16 instead of 14 and ran `yarn upgrade`.

Please advise how can I resolve this?

Comment: To double-check, do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the host's `node_modules` directory, when you `COPY . .`?  Are any of the `RUN apk ...` lines required to reproduce the issue, or can you delete those as part of your [mcve]?

Comment: I run it in gitlab and `node_modules` does not exist in the repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I replaced the various commands in `package.json` from `npm` to use `yarn`.